# Stability analysis of the numerical integration of the Euler-Bernoulli PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences

In the Euler-Bernoulli model the equations of motion of a vibrating beam are
given by
$$
\mu X_{tt}+EIX_{zzzz}=0,
$$
where $X(z, t)$ is the deflexion at height $z$ and at time $t$.
We discretize this function in the following way
$$
X(z, t) \rightarrow X(z_j, t_n)\rightarrow X(z_0+jh, n\delta t)\rightarrow X_{j,n},
$$
where $h$ is the grid size and $\delta t$ is the integration time-step.
The time derivative is discretized by the following approximation
$$
X_{tt}(z, t)\approx \frac{X_{j,n+1}+X_{j, n-1}-2X_{j,n}}{\delta t^2},
$$
which has an error of order $\mathcal{O}(\delta t^2)$.
The central finite-difference discretization of $X_{zzzz}$ used at interior
points of the grid is given by
$$
X_{zzzz}(z, t)\approx\dfrac{X_{j+2, n}-4X_{j+1, n}+6X_{j, n}-4X_{j-1, n}+X_{j-2,
n}}{h^4},
$$
whose error is of the order of $\mathcal{O}(h^2)$.
A simple and straight forward explicit method for the numerical time
integration of interior points of the grid is given by
$$
X_{j, n+1}= 2X_{j, n}-X_{j, n-1}+\dfrac{\delta t^2EI}{h^4\mu}(X_{j+2, n}
-4X_{j+1, n}+6X_{j, n}-4X_{j-1, n}+X_{j-2, n})
$$
We use clamped boundary conditions at $z=0$, $X(0, t)=X_z(0, t)=0$
and free boundary conditions at $z=\ell_0$, $X_{zz}(\ell_0, t)=X_{zzz}(\ell_0,
t)=0$.

We next analyse the stability of this integration scheme using the von
Neumann stability criterion. Suppose $X_{j,n}=g^ne^{ikz_j}$, where $z_j=z_0+jh$.
We obtain then
\begin{align}
g&=2-1/g+\dfrac{\delta
t^2EI}{h^4\mu}\left[e^{i2kh}-4e^{ikh}+6-4e^{-ikh}+e^{-2ikh}\right]\\
&=2-1/g+\dfrac{2\delta t^2EI}{h^4\mu}
\left[3-4\cos(kh)+\cos(2kh)\right]
\end{align}
with the notation
$$
\beta = 1+\alpha\left[3-4\cos(kh)+\cos(2kh)\right],
$$
where $\alpha=\dfrac{\delta t^2EI}{h^4\mu}$.
We then find that the equation for $g$ is given by
$$
g^2-2\beta g+1=0.
$$
The solutions are given by
$$
g_\pm= \beta\pm\sqrt{\beta^2-1}.
$$
Hence, if $\beta>1$, this method of integration is unstable.
One can show that $\beta>1$.
Therefore, we have to find another integration method.
We now modify the previous explicit method and implement an implicit method
for the numerical time integration.
It is given by
\begin{align}
X_{i, n+1} &= 2X_{i, n}-X_{i, n-1}+\dfrac{\delta t^2EI}{2h^4\mu}
\left[X_{i+2, n}+X_{i+2, n+1} -4(X_{i+1, n}+X_{i+1, n+1})\right.\\
&\left.+6(X_{i, n}+X_{i, n+1})-4(X_{i-1, n}+X_{i-1, n+1})+X_{i-2, n}+X_{i-2,
n+1}\right]
\end{align}
With the substitution $X_{j,n}=g^ne^{ikz_j}$, we find
$$
\kappa g-\gamma g+1=0,
$$
where
\begin{align}
\kappa &=1-\alpha[3-4\cosh(kh)+\cosh(2kh)],\\
\gamma &=2+\alpha[3-4\cosh(kh)+\cosh(2kh)].
\end{align}
The solution for the quadratic equation in $g$ is
$$
g_\pm=\frac{\gamma\pm\sqrt{\gamma^2-4\kappa}}{2\kappa}.
$$
One can verify that $|g_\pm|>1$, hence this implies this method is also unstable.
Could anyone provide a stable (finite difference or finite element) numerical integration method for the Euler-Bernoulli equations?